# How to extract specific codes from string in separate columns?

Tags: python, regex

I have data in the following format.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVXyz.png)

[Data Sample Excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oRuADsIJfXZIgvI7JpcwtGGueXWx3lUOtxpjffen1oY/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to extract the codes from the column "DIAGNOSIS" and paste each code in a separate column after the "DIAGNOSIS" column. I Know the regular expression to be used to match this which is

[A-TV-Z][0-9][0-9AB].?[0-9A-TV-Z]{0,4}

source: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/05/05/regex_icd_codes/

These are called ICD10 codes represented like Z01.2, E11, etc. The Above expression is meant to match all ICD10 codes.

But I am not sure how to use this expression in python code to do the above task.

The problem that I am trying to solve is?

1. Count the Total number of Codes assigned for all patients?
2. Count Total number of UNIQUE code assigned (since multiple patients might have same code assigned)
3. Generate data Code wise - i.e if I select code Z01.2, I want to extract Patient data (maybe PATID, MOBILE NUMBER OR ANY OTHER COLUMN OR ALL) who have been assigned this code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are on the good track with the regex. Just a typo to correct (missing backslash before the dot), it should be `r"[A-TV-Z][0-9][0-9AB]\.?[0-9A-TV-Z]{0,4}"gm`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/q63X4J/1 . Regards

Answer (score 0):

Using Python Pandas as follows.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter='\t')

pattern = '([A-TV-Z][0-9][0-9AB]\.?[0-9A-TV-Z]{0,4})'

df['CODES'] = df['DIAGNOSIS'].str.findall(pattern)

df['Length'] = df['CODES'].str.len()

print(f"Total Codes: {df['Length'].sum()}")

all_codes = df['CODES'].sum()#.set()
unique_codes = set(all_codes)
print(f'all codes {all_codes}\nCount: {len(all_codes)}')
print(f'unique codes {unique_codes}\nCount: {len(unique_codes)}')

# Select patients with code Z01.2
patients=df[df['CODES'].apply(', '.join).str.contains('Z01.2')]
# Show selected columns
print(patients.loc[:, ['PATID', 'PATIENT_NAME', 'MOBILE_NUMBER']])
```

**Explanation**

Imported data as tab-delimited CSV

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter='\t'
```

Resulting DataFrame df

```
  PATID PATIENT_NAME  MOBILE_NUMBER  EMAIL_ADDRESS GENDER PATIENT_AGE  \
0     11          Mac          98765  ab1@gmail.com      F        51 Y   
1     22          Sac          98766  ab1@gmail.com      F        24 Y   
2     33          Tac          98767  ab1@gmail.com      M        43 Y   
3     44          Lac          98768  ab1@gmail.com      M        54 Y   

  DISTRICT   CLINIC                                          DIAGNOSIS  
0     Mars  Clinic1  Z01.2 - Dental examinationC50 - Malignant neop...  
1     Moon  Clinic2  S83.6 - Sprain and strain of other and unspeci...  
2    Earth  Clinic3  K60.1 - Chronic anal fissureZ20.9 - Contact wi...  
3   Saturn  Clinic4  E11 - Type 2 diabetes mellitusE78.5 - Hyperlip...
```

Extract from DIAGNOSIS column using the specified pattern

Add an escape character before . otherwise, it would be a wildcard and match any character (no difference on data supplied).

```
pattern = '([A-TV-Z][0-9][0-9AB]\.?[0-9A-TV-Z]{0,4})'
df['CODES'] = df['DIAGNOSIS'].str.findall(pattern)
```

df['CODES'] each row in the column is a list of codes

```
0                              [Z01.2, C50 , Z10.0]
1                             [S83.6, L05.0, Z20.9]
2                       [K60.1, Z20.9, J06.9, C50 ]
3    [E11 , E78.5, I10 , E55 , E79.0, Z24.0, Z01.2]

Name: CODES, dtype: object
```

Add length column to df DataFrame

```
df['Length'] = df['CODES'].str.len()
```

df['Length']--correspond to length of each code list

```
0    3
1    3
2    4
3    7

Name: Length, dtype: int64
```

Total Codes Used--sum over the length of codes

```
df['Length'].sum()
```

Total Codes: 17

All Codes Used--concatenating all the code lists

```
all_codes = df['CODES'].sum()

['Z01.2', 'C50 ', 'Z10.0', 'S83.6', 'L05.0', 'Z20.9', 'K60.1', 'Z20.9', 'J06.9', 'C50
 ', 'E11 ', 'E78.5', 'I10 ', 'E55 ', 'E79.0', 'Z24.0', 'Z01.2']
```

Count: 17

Unique Codes Used--take the set() of the list of all codes

```
unique_codes = set(all_codes)

{'L05.0', 'S83.6', 'E79.0', 'Z01.2', 'I10 ', 'J06.9', 'K60.1', 'E11 ', 'Z24.0', 'Z
10.0', 'E55 ', 'E78.5', 'Z20.9', 'C50 '}

Count: 14
```

Select patients by code (i.e. Z01.2)

```
patients=df[df['CODES'].apply(', '.join).str.contains('Z01.2')]
```

Show PATIE, PATIENT_NAME and MOBILE_NUMBER for these patients

```
print(patients.loc[:, ['PATID', 'PATIENT_NAME', 'MOBILE_NUMBER']])
```

Result

```
   PATID PATIENT_NAME  MOBILE_NUMBER
0     11          Mac          98765
3     44          Lac          98768
```

Comment: Hello DarrylG. Sorry for delay in response. I was out because of some personal reasons. Today I tried your code on original data and it worked fine until all_codes = df['CODES'].sum(). Here i am getting an error can "only concatenate list (not "int") to list"

Comment: Ultimately I want to export in excel the list of all codes in one column and codes count in secodn column. Then i will do my analysis in excel.

Comment: @Nikki--hi Nikki, welcome back.  Here's a [link to my running the code](https://repl.it/join/rfxwkuqt-darrylgurganiou) on your original data which I downloaded as an Excel file.  All I did was download your file to Excel then uploaded the file to a online Python repl to run the software.  Are you saying the software does not work for you on the same Excel file?

Comment: Hello @DarrylG . Whati found out was that the CODES list column had "Blank" rows and some empty list []. I removed them from the list and then the code "all_codes = df['CODES'].sum()" was able to run without any error. So no issues now.

Comment: Also i want to thank you for the the approah and the code "pattern = '([A-TV-Z][0-9][0-9AB]\.?[0-9A-TV-Z]{0,4})'

df['CODES'] = df['DIAGNOSIS'].str.findall(pattern)" . This has helped me extract codes in a very short time. Earlier i was using a code that used to take hours to extract data and sometimes i had to stop the run.

Comment: This was the code. Can you help me understand why this code is slow. regex = r"[A-TV-Z][0-9][0-9AB]\.?[0-9A-TV-Z]{0,4}"
df_code= pd.DataFrame()
for row in df["DIAGNOSIS"].values:
    matches = re.findall(regex, str(row))
    if matches:
        df_code = df_code.append([matches], ignore_index=True)

df_code.fillna('', inplace=True)
df_code.index += 1

Comment: @nikki--Pandas for loops in are slow.  For why take a look at this article [how to make your pandas loops faster](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06) describes.

Comment: @nikki-an easy way to make the code faster is to processing the data in Python then place into Pandas DataFrame at the end as follows: `def test2(df_param):
  regex = r"[A-TV-Z][0-9][0-9AB]\.?[0-9A-TV-Z]{0,4}" 
  data = []
  for row in df_param["DIAGNOSIS"].values: 
    matches = re.findall(regex, row)
    if matches: 
      data.append(matches)

  df_code= pd.DataFrame(data)
  df_code.fillna('', inplace=True)'.  I replicated rows to generate more test data, and things where ~100x faster then your code.